# json array recursive loop in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

how to recursive loop for json object data key in javascript.

Please check below json object:

```
{
    "data":[
        {
            "label": "Test-1",
            "data": "Test-1",
            "updated_at": "2020-3-23",
            "created_at": "2020-3-19",
            "expanded": true,
            "children": [
                {
                    "label": "Test-1.1",
                    "data": "Test-1.1",
                    "updated_at": "2020-3-19",
                    "created_at": "2020-3-19",
                    "expanded": true,
                    "children": [
                        {
                            "label": "Test-1.1.1",
                            "updated_at": "2020-3-19",
                            "created_at": "2020-3-19",
                            "expanded": true,
                            "children": [
                                {
                                    "label": "Test-1.1.1.1",
                                    "data": "Test-1.1.1.1",
                                    "updated_at": "2020-3-19",
                                    "created_at": "2020-3-19",
                                    "expanded": true
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            "label": "Test-1.1.2",
                            "data": "Test-1.1.2",
                            "updated_at": "2020-3-19",
                            "created_at": "2020-3-19",
                            "expanded": true
                        },
                        {
                            "label": "Test-1.1.3",
                            "data": "Test-1.1.3",
                            "updated_at": "2020-3-19",
                            "created_at": "2020-3-19",
                            "expanded": true
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "label": "Test-2",
            "data": "Test-2",
            "updated_at": "2020-3-19",
            "created_at": "2020-3-19",
            "expanded": true
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: This question is unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is sample `recur` function to print `label`.

```js
const items = {
  data: [
    {
      label: "Test-1",
      data: "Test-1",
      updated_at: "2020-3-23",
      created_at: "2020-3-19",
      expanded: true,
      children: [
        {
          label: "Test-1.1",
          data: "Test-1.1",
          updated_at: "2020-3-19",
          created_at: "2020-3-19",
          expanded: true,
          children: [
            {
              label: "Test-1.1.1",
              updated_at: "2020-3-19",
              created_at: "2020-3-19",
              expanded: true,
              children: [
                {
                  label: "Test-1.1.1.1",
                  data: "Test-1.1.1.1",
                  updated_at: "2020-3-19",
                  created_at: "2020-3-19",
                  expanded: true
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              label: "Test-1.1.2",
              data: "Test-1.1.2",
              updated_at: "2020-3-19",
              created_at: "2020-3-19",
              expanded: true
            },
            {
              label: "Test-1.1.3",
              data: "Test-1.1.3",
              updated_at: "2020-3-19",
              created_at: "2020-3-19",
              expanded: true
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      label: "Test-2",
      data: "Test-2",
      updated_at: "2020-3-19",
      created_at: "2020-3-19",
      expanded: true
    }
  ]
};

const recur = arr => {
  arr.forEach(item => {
    console.log(item.label);
    if (item.children) {
      recur(item.children);
    }
  });
};

recur(items.data);
```